# CakePHP Posting Error

Tags: php, cakephp

***Issue:***
Getting the following error in my controller function.  The initial save is working, it looks like it's getting choked up on the nested save function.  Thoughts as to why i would be getting this error?

***Error:***
Fatal Error
Error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object 
File: C:\metroapps\Orders\app\Controller\OrderLogsController.php
Line: 121

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp

***Code***:

```
    public function quickAdd($notes = null,$order_id =null, $log_type_id = null) {
            $this->request->data['OrderLog']['log_type_id'] = $log_type_id;
            $this->request->data['OrderLog']['order_id'] = $order_id;
            $this->request->data['OrderLog']['notes'] = $notes;
            $this->OrderLog->create();
    if ($this->OrderLog->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The order log has been saved.'));
                $this->Order->read(null, $order_id);
                //set checkedout to false
                $this->Order->set('checked_out', 0);
                $this->Order->set('checked_out_by', null);
                $this->Order->save();
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'orders','action' => 'view',$order_id));
    } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The order log could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

    $orders = $this->OrderLog->Order->find('list');
    $logTypes = $this->OrderLog->LogType->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('orders', 'logTypes'));
}
```

Comment: Two problems may be. if you are calling function on a model object then you have to load it in your function where you are calling it. If you are calling a controller function then try to create object for that first and then use it to call  that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to fix your model relations and access the related model properly.

Make sure your Order and OrderLog models are related (both directions)

```
// in Order model
public $hasMany = array('OrderLog');

// in OrderLog model
public $belongsTo = array('Order');
```

and then in your function do

```
$this->OrderLog->Order-> ..

// instead of $this->Order
```